# help me with the linq query syntax to read elements not in a range

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to remove all reports from a list, which are not created in a certain range of calender weeks (a property of each report). Since I want to learn LINQ, I started with this:

```
List<Reporte> reports = ReadAllReports();

List<sbyte> importantWeeks = GetRelevantWeeks(); // e.g. 49,51,52,1,2,3

// Remove irrelevant reports (from irrelevant calender weeks) doesn't work
IEnumerable<Reporte> importantReports = from oneReport in reports where oneReport.Kalenderwoche ??INRANGE importantWeeks?? select oneReport;
```

Could you help me with the correct syntax for the linq statement?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *suspect* you want:

```
var importantReports = from oneReport in reports
                       where importantWeeks.Contains(oneReport.ReportWeek)
                       select oneReport;
```

which could be written more concisely as:

```
var importantReports = reports.Where(x => importantWeeks.Contains(x.ReportWeek));
```

Note that if `importantWeeks` becomes larger, you may want to consider using `HashSet<int>` instead of `List<int>`

Answer (score 1):

var importantReports = reports.Where(r => importantWeeks.Contains(r.KalenderWoche)));